# IP address for django-axes logins does not show

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings

I have django-axes running with my Django app and so far everything works fine, however, in the django-axes admin section, the IP addresses do not seem to work. It just shows a "-".

Is there perhaps a setting I should configure for django-axes to enable this or is it one of my Django project settings that prevent this? Maybe one of these:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 2592000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = 'same-origin'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please set `AXES_META_PRECEDENCE_ORDER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR')`. Or add your header configuration.

Comment: Yeah, can confirm this works.